# Default value not clearing off in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react jsx screen snippet as shown below:

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import ErrorCodes from './ErrorCodes.jsx';

export default function RegisterScreen()
{

  const [Device_ID,setDevice_ID] = useState('');
  const [Registerar_UserName,setRegisterar_UserName] = useState('');
  const [Registerar_Email,setRegisterar_Email] = useState('');
  const [Organisation_Name,setOrganisation_Name] = useState('');
  const [Organisation_Email,setOrganisation_Email] = useState('');
  const [Password,setPassword] = useState('');
  const [ReenterPassword,setReenterPassword] = useState('');

  const [Device_ID_Error,setDevice_ID_Error] = useState('');
  const [Registerar_UserName_Error,setRegisterar_UserName_Error] = useState('');
  const [Registerar_Email_Error,setRegisterar_Email_Error] = useState('');
  const [Organisation_Name_Error,setOrganisation_Name_Error] = useState('');
  const [Organisation_Email_Error,setOrganisation_Email_Error] = useState('');
  const [ReenterPassword_Error,setReenterPassword_Error] = useState('');
  
    return <Form className = "FormAligner">
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
      <Form.Label>Registered Device ID</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="text"
      onChange = {e=>{
        setDevice_ID(e.target.value);
        if(Device_ID.length!=12)
        setDevice_ID_Error(ErrorCodes[5]);
        else
        setDevice_ID_Error(ErrorCodes[0]);

      }}
      placeholder="Device ID" value={Device_ID}/>
      <Form.Text className="text-muted">
        {Device_ID_Error}
        </Form.Text>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
      <Form.Label>Industry Name</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Industry Name" 
      onChange={e=>{
        setRegisterar_UserName(e.target.value);
        if(Registerar_UserName.length===0)
        setRegisterar_UserName_Error(ErrorCodes[1]);
        else
        setRegisterar_UserName_Error(ErrorCodes[0]);

      }}
      value={Registerar_UserName}/>
      <Form.Text className="text-muted">
        {Registerar_UserName_Error}
        </Form.Text>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
      <Form.Label>Industry Email</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Industry Email"
      value={Registerar_Email}
      onChange={e=>{setRegisterar_Email(e.target.value)
        let regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if(regex.test(Registerar_Email))
        setRegisterar_Email_Error(ErrorCodes[0]);
        else
        setRegisterar_Email_Error(ErrorCodes[4]);
      }}/>
      <Form.Text className="text-muted">
        {Registerar_Email_Error}
        </Form.Text>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
      <Form.Label>Organisation Name</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Organisation Name"
      value={Organisation_Name}
      onChange={e=>{setOrganisation_Name(e.target.value);
        if(Organisation_Name.length===0)
        setOrganisation_Name_Error(ErrorCodes[1]);
        else
        setOrganisation_Name_Error(ErrorCodes[0]);
        }}/>
      <Form.Text className="text-muted">
        {Organisation_Name_Error}
        </Form.Text>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
    <Form.Label>Industry Email</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Industry Email"
    value={Organisation_Email}
    onChange={e=>{
      setOrganisation_Email(e.target.value);
      let regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if(regex.test(Organisation_Email))
        setOrganisation_Email_Error(ErrorCodes[0]);
        else
        setOrganisation_Email_Error(ErrorCodes[4]);

    }}/>
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
        {Organisation_Email_Error}
        </Form.Text>
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Enter Password"
    value={Password}
    onChange={e=>setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
    </Form.Group>
   <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
    <Form.Label>Re-enter Password</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Enter Password"
    value={ReenterPassword}
    onChange={e=>{
      setReenterPassword(e.target.value);
      if(ReenterPassword!=Password)
      {
        setReenterPassword_Error(ErrorCodes[6]);
      }
      else
      setReenterPassword_Error(ErrorCodes[0]);
    }}/>
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
        {ReenterPassword_Error}
        </Form.Text>
    </Form.Group>
    <Button variant="primary" className="Submit-Button" type="submit"
    onClick={async(event)=>{
      event.preventDefault();
      const JSONString = {Device_ID,Registerar_UserName,Registerar_Email,Organisation_Name,Organisation_Email,Password,ReenterPassword};
      console.log(JSON.stringify(JSONString));
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/register',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(JSONString)
      });
      if(response.ok){
        console.log("Response recieved");
      }
    }}>
      Register
    </Button>
  </Form>
}
```

Here's how it looks:
[image]

For some reason, I don't know but the fields Industry Email and password always comes pre-filled. I tried to do so many things but not able to get why is this happening by default when other fields are empty.

Do I add some `preventDefault` function to avoid default actions? I know there are some unconventional ways to stop this from happening but I want to know the core concept to why is this even happening at the first place when I haven't done any such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your browser is autocompleting those fields, you should check that and try to use `autocomplete="off"` in your inputs or your form to prevent that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that since those fields are set to type "email" and "password", its likely that your browser is auto filling these fields for you after having clicked yes on the "remember credentials" dialog. You can undo this by removing them in your browser credential manager.

Comment: Ahhh I see... yeah maybe that could be a reason using autocomplete="off" worked for me.